# Eclipse : Conditional Break Points inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have written a small Sample program to see about Eclipse Conditional Break Points

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("One3");
        String str = null;
        String name = str;
    }
}
```

And inside the  Eclipse Debugger Perspective , under BreakPoints , i have set condition as shown 
str!=null

Please see the image here of it .
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kdrc0g&s=5

From this what i understood is that , the condition (str!=null) doesn't meet the code , so the debugger will give a warning .

Please tell me if my understanding is correct ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Debug mode, when the condition is satisfied, the code execution will pause at that point, allowing you to observe variable values, continue execution step by step and such.

Comment: There is a instance variable str  defined , but i still could not understand .

Comment: I cannot open the image you have provided. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: @yyyi777: there is no instance variable str defined. There is a local str variable defined. Evene if there was an instance str variable defined, it would not matter since main is static and thus doesn't have access to instance variables.

Comment: I am sorry, no matter how much I try, I fail to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting a breakpoint with a condition on the variable `str` at a location where there is no variable `str`. So obviously, the condition is impossible to evaluate.

If the breakpoint was on the last line, then it would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Is the break point defined before the str declaration ? If it's the case, it's normal this break point doesn't work because the str string is unknow.